The double-slit experiment with the pit in the screen
The main question is contained in the experiment #6. But first, 5 simple experiments are described to describe the designations that are used in the question of the experiment #6.
In the double-slit experiment, the slits are labeled α and β. A region C is designated on the screen. The power passes through the open slit: ${P_\alpha} = {P_\beta} = {P_{\rm{sl}}}$
Experiment #1: Both slits are open, and the screen is a flat solid surface. This is well described and shown in the diagram (which is taken from here). The total power of light on the screen is ${P_{\rm{scr 1}}} = {P_\alpha} + {P_\beta} = 2 \cdot {P_{\rm{sl}}}$. The power of light outside the region C is ${P_{{\rm{scr}} - {\rm{C }}1}} = {P_{{\rm{scr }}1}} - {P_{{\rm{C }}1}} = 2 \cdot {P_{{\rm{sl}}}} - {P_{{\rm{C }}1}}$.

Experiment #2: Slit α is open. Slit β is closed. The total power of light on the screen is ${P_{{\rm{scr 2}}}} = {P_\alpha } = {P_{{\rm{sl}}}}$. The power of light outside the region C is ${P_{{\rm{scr}} - {\rm{C }}2}} = {P_{{\rm{scr }}2}} - {P_{{\rm{C }}2}} = {P_{{\rm{sl}}}} - {P_{{\rm{C }}2}}$.
Experiment #3: Slit β is open. Slit α is closed. The total power of light on the screen is ${P_{{\rm{scr 3}}}} = {P_\beta } = {P_{{\rm{sl}}}}$. The power of light outside the region C is ${P_{{\rm{scr}} - {\rm{C }}3}} = {P_{{\rm{scr }}3}} - {P_{{\rm{C }}3}} = {P_{{\rm{sl}}}} - {P_{{\rm{C }}3}}$.
Considering symmetry, the index 23 is added:
$${P_{{\rm{C }}2}} = {P_{{\rm{C }}3}} = {P_{{\rm{C 2}}3}} \Rightarrow {P_{{\rm{scr}} - {\rm{C }}2}} = {P_{{\rm{scr}} - {\rm{C }}3}} = {P_{{\rm{scr}} - {\rm{C 2}}3}}$$
In Experiment #1, the power of light in the region C is greater than the sum in Experiments #2 and #3. Therefore, the power of the rest of the screen is less:
$${P_{{\rm{C }}1}} > 2{P_{{\rm{C 2}}3}} \Rightarrow {P_{{\rm{scr}} - {\rm{C }}1}} < 2{P_{{\rm{scr}} - {\rm{C 2}}3}}$$
Next, the conical pit with A and B is made in the screen within the region C, as shown in the next diagram. The region A sees slit α and does not see slit β. The region B sees slit β and does not see slit α. This means that a straight ray from A falls on α, but not on β. A straight ray from B falls on β, but not on α. Because the angle between A and B is less than the angle between the straight rays from the slit α and β to the screen centre, as shown in the next diagram. Diffraction at the edges of the transition from regions A and B to the flat screen is neglected, assuming the region C size is much larger than the wavelength.
The experiments #4 and #5 are repeated experiments #2 and #3 with the new screen. The power in the regions A and B can be easily determined:
$${P_{{\rm{A }}4}} = {P_{{\rm{{C} }}2}} = {P_{{\rm{{C} }}23}}$$
$${P_{{\rm{B }}4}} = 0$$
$${P_{{\rm{A }}5}} = 0$$
$${P_{{\rm{B }}5}} = {P_{{\rm{{C} }}3}} = {P_{{\rm{{C} }}23}}$$
$${P_{{\rm{A }}4}} + {P_{{\rm{B }}4}} + {P_{{\rm{A }}5}} + {P_{{\rm{B }}5}} < {P_{{\rm{C }}1}}$$
$${P_{{\rm{scr}} - \left( {{\rm{A}} + {\rm{B}}} \right){\rm{ }}4}} = {P_{{\rm{scr}} - {\rm{{C} }}2}} = {P_{{\rm{scr}} - {\rm{{C} }}23}}$$
$${P_{{\rm{scr}} - \left( {{\rm{A}} + {\rm{B}}} \right){\rm{ }}5}} = {P_{{\rm{scr}} - {\rm{{C} }}3}} = {P_{{\rm{scr}} - {\rm{{C} }}23}}$$

Experiment #6: Both slits are open, and there is the conical pit in the screen.
What will be the power in the regions A and B? What will be the power in the the rest of the screen? Is there the right inequality (1) or (2) or something else?
The conservation of energy requires:
$${P_{{\rm{A }}6}} + {P_{{\rm{B }}6}} + {P_{{\rm{scr}} - {\rm{{C} }}6}} = {P_{{\rm{scr 6}}}} = {P_\alpha } + {P_\beta } = 2 \cdot {P_{{\rm{sl}}}}$$
If the power outside the region C corresponds to Experiment #1, then the power in the regions A and B must change and become greater than in Experiments #4 and #5:
$${P_{{\rm{scr}} - {\rm{{C} }}6}} = {P_{{\rm{scr}} - {\rm{{C} }}1}}$$
$${P_{{\rm{A }}6}} + {P_{{\rm{B }}6}} = {P_{{\rm{scr 6}}}} - {P_{{\rm{scr}} - {\rm{{C} }}6}} = 2 \cdot {P_{{\rm{sl}}}} - {P_{{\rm{scr}} - {\rm{{C} }}1}} = {P_{{\rm{C }}1}} > 2{P_{{\rm{C 2}}3}} = {P_{{\rm{A }}4}} + {P_{{\rm{B }}4}} + {P_{{\rm{A }}5}} + {P_{{\rm{B }}5}}$$
$$ \left\{ \begin{array}{l}
{P_{{\rm{scr}} - {\rm{{C} }}6}} = {P_{{\rm{scr}} - {\rm{{C} }}1}}\\
{P_{{\rm{A }}6}} + {P_{{\rm{B }}6}} > 2{P_{{\rm{C 2}}3}}
\end{array} \right. \qquad(1) $$
But straight ray from each of the slit falls on only one corresponding region. Each of the regions sees only one corresponding slit. How can the power on it depend on whether the second slit is open or closed? "If light propagates like waves, why can't I see around corners?" and "Can light beams (e.g. from a laser) visibly interfere if they cross in mid-air?" are related questions.
And if the power in the regions A and B remains the same as in Experiments #4 and #5, then the power of the rest of the screen must change and become greater than in Experiment #1:
$${P_{{\rm{A }}6}} + {P_{{\rm{B }}6}} = {P_{{\rm{A }}4}} + {P_{{\rm{B }}4}} + {P_{{\rm{A }}5}} + {P_{{\rm{B }}5}} = 2{P_{{\rm{C 2}}3}}$$
$${P_{{\rm{scr}} - {\rm{{C} }}6}} = {P_{{\rm{scr 6}}}} - \left( {{P_{{\rm{A }}6}} + {P_{{\rm{B }}6}}} \right) = 2 \cdot {P_{{\rm{sl}}}} - 2{P_{{\rm{C 2}}3}} = 2{P_{{\rm{scr}} - {\rm{{C} }}23}} > {P_{{\rm{scr}} - {\rm{{C} }}1}}\\$$
$$ \left\{ \begin{array}{l}
{P_{{\rm{scr}} - {\rm{{C} }}6}} > {P_{{\rm{scr}} - {\rm{{C} }}1}}\\
{P_{{\rm{A }}6}} + {P_{{\rm{B }}6}} = 2{P_{{\rm{C 2}}3}}
\end{array} \right. \qquad(2) $$
But how can the power on the rest of the screen change due to the appearance of pits in it?
In this closely related question “ Young's double slits with a hole in the screen (Wheeler observer) ”, the power is not considered and screen shapes is other. Also, judging by the lack of a comprehensive answer, the question remains underestimated.
Although the experiment is very simple from a practical point of view. Presumably, it has already been conducted and has explanations of the results... but where?

Can you clarify what you mean by The region A sees slit α and does not see slit β. The region B sees slit β and does not see slit α. please? A and B are both inside C, correct?

@MariusLadegårdMeyer
This means that a straight ray from A falls on α, but not on β. A straight ray from B falls on β, but not on α. Flat C is in the experiments 1,2,3. The pit with A and B is in the experiments 4,5,6. A and B is instead of C.

The total power on the screen and through the opening always adds up to the power that comes through both slits minus the power that gets reflected into the two slits (which you didn't mention, I believe). This is just energy conservation. If you get a different result, then you simply made a mistake in your assumptions that diffraction doesn't play a role. In any case, you can calculate all of this exactly using Maxwell's equations, it's just not very pleasant to do. I also have no idea what "both regions only see one slit" means. That's simply not the case in wave optics.

@FlatterMann
There was not "both regions only see one slit" in the text. I tried more to clarify about "regions see slit".

can you summarize the surprising result we're trying to explain in words?

@JEB   It is question about the double-slit experiment with the pit in the screen. There is not result. The main part of the question is highlighted by bold text: "What will be the power in the regions A and B? What will be the power in the the rest of the screen?". I clarificated the main question. But in order to formulate this question I had to write a lot before it.

Waves don't propagate the way you think they do. LIght from either slit diffracts going through C, so claiming that A (or B) does or does not "see" a slit is irrelevant.

@JonCuster
The region C size is much larger than the wavelength. Even in this case, will diffraction (at the edge from A to screen and the edge from B to screen) matter? This is not obvious.

'This means that a straight ray from A falls on α, but not on β. A straight ray from B falls on β, but not on α. ' This only makes sense in the short wavelength limit, when there is no diffraction at all.

The EM field decides where the power goes. Long before the first photon leaves the source the excited electron in the source is already disturbing the apparatus EM field, if this field sees the 2 slits open then the diffraction pattern concentrates the power in the central peak. The experiment has been done with single photons, each photon has its own path as determined by the EM field, there is no cancelation or loss of energy.
I don't think anyone has really done your experiment with the pit. What you are taught in high school today is based in 1930s textbooks.  WWII and the nuclear age and then the electronic age drew all the best scientists ... only ancient academics still focus on the DSE.

Diffraction at the edges of the transition from regions A and B to the flat screen is neglected, assuming the region C size is much larger than the wavelength. "If light propagates like waves, why can't I see around corners? [ https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/691509/if-light-propagates-like-waves-why-cant-i-see-around-corner ]" is related about the diffraction.

@lmyaf You are doing a diffraction experiment but are demanding that no diffraction takes place. That makes no sense whatsoever from the beginning.

Absolutely nobody cared about the double slit at any time in the QM context. It's a classical wave experiment from 1801 that was first analyzed by Young. IF quantum mechanics would even show up in it, then Young would have found out about it almost a full century before Planck. The simple fact is that it doesn't. Planck's constant is nowhere to be found here and we aren't doing any multi-quantum correlation function measurements, either. Diffraction is mean field theory, pure and simple. That nobody cares about diffraction using Maxwell is not true. Optics and the wireless industry does.

@Imyaf To be really scientific we must separate diffraction and interference, many scientists do not realize that water waves going thru a single slit do NOT make an interference pattern! (for water we need 2 slits).  Let's define diffraction = spreading (i.e. waves spread passing an edge) and let's define 2 types of interference: type 1 From matter waves

@Imyaf To be really scientific we must separate diffraction and interference, many scientists do not realize that water waves going thru a single slit do NOT make an interference pattern! (for water we need 2 slits).  Let's define diffraction = spreading (i.e. waves spread passing an edge) and let's define 2 types of interference: Type1-From matter waves, crests and troughs can meet and temporarily superimpose, but all waves reemerge and Type2 - waves that are resonant (like a piano string) and only accept certain frequencies or path lengths. For light the EM field makes all photons Type2.

@FlatterMann Yes in radio etc fields and "interference" are important. We've known how to calculate that since 1930s (Bode plot).  Also please see my comment above, the word diffraction is used to freely IMO.

@PhysicsDave You mean since Huygens and Fresnel? The qualitative behavior of waves was known for centuries before that. The quantitative behavior of electromagnetic waves was known since Maxwell.
